# The Notion Of Degenerate Two Player Game

Tags: game-theory

I try to get the intuitive understanding of the notion "degenerate two player game".

**Definition**. A two-player game is called non degenerate if no mixed strategy
of support size $k$ has more than $k$ pure best responses.

*What's so special about degenerate game, why sometimes we should consider degenerate case and non degenerate case separately?*

*Whether the definition of degenerate game is applied to non two player game(so far I saw only 2 player version)?*

Consider the following two player game in standard form.

$0/0  \space \space \space \space \space     10/10$

$0/0 \space \space \space \space \space     10/10$

When the column player picks pure strategy to play column two. The row player has more than one pure best response: the first row and the second row.

*Does it mean that this always happens in degenerate game, that we have few solutions with the same payoffs for each player?* On the other hand, in the above example, we can just use mixed strategy for the row player: play the first row with probability 0.5 and play the second row with probability 0.5.

As you see I really confused by the definition of degenerate game and will appreciate any help.

Comment: Where does the definition come from?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker the definition seems to be definition 3.2 here: http://www.maths.lse.ac.uk/Personal/stengel/TEXTE/agt-stengel.pdf

Comment: @HAL9000 Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 5):

> Does it mean that this always happens in degenerate game, that we have few solutions with the same payoffs for each player?

Not few. Infinite. In the example row player can play infinite mixed strategies which are best response to the column player strategy. And yes, this is a property of all degenerate games.

> On the other hand, in the above example, we can just use mixed strategy for the row player: play the first row with probability 0.5 and play the second row with probability 0.5.

If you choose that mixed strategy the game remains *degenerate*. In fact the dual definition says that a 2-player game is *degenerate* if **exists** a strategy of support *k* for which the number of pure best responses of the adversary are more than *k*.

The definition can be applied also in games with more than two players. If, in a *n*-players game, exists a strategy *s* of n-1 players, such that the *n*-th player has a number of pure best responses greater than the size of the smallest support in the strategy *s*, then the game is *degenerate*. 
One example follows:

```
     A                 B
0/0/0 0/10/10     0/0/0 0/10/10
0/0/0 0/10/10     0/0/0 0/10/10
```

The first player (player 1) can choose which table (A or B) to use, while other two players are *row* player and *column* player.
If player 1 chooses a strategy of (0.5,0.5) and *column* player chooses the second column (support 1), then the *row* player is *indifferent* to play first or second row (2 best responses). This game is *degenerate* because Nash equilibria are not isolated points.